# Change integer or string variable to base 16 in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert base of variable may be in string or integer or byte. I can change the base of a constant number like 10 by using &H e.g {&H10} to A. But with a variable it throws a syntax error. Please Help

This is the code:

```
Private Sub writeButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles writeButton.Click
    Dim a() As Byte = {&H(Slave), &H3, &H0, &H2, &H0, &H4, &H(CRC)}
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4.01)
    SerialPort1.Write(a, 0, a.Length)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4.01)       
End Sub
```

Comment: the problem is in the code you are not showing

Comment: You can't use Integer.Parse, Or Integer.ToString("X") ?

Comment: You do not need the numbers in any particular format: a number is still the same number regardless of the base it is represented in. The only slight problem would be if `Slave` or `CRC` were more than one byte.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim someVaraible As IConvertible = "10" 'Can be any type that implements IConvertable
Dim base16 = CInt(Convert.ChangeType(someVaraible, TypeCode.Int32)).ToString("X")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'to string:
YourString = CStr(Convert.ToString(YourString, 16).ToString())
'to integer:
YourString = Convert.ToInt32(YourString, 16)
```